# The meaning of "That way, she could forget the 'immodesty' of what she was doing."

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> [She] took trouble to learn her lines and repeated the scene until it was perfect. That way, she could forget the "immodesty" of what she was doing.

The [passage](https://www.economist.com/news/obituary/21565580-sylvia-kristel-star-%E2%80%9Cemmanuelle%E2%80%9D-died-october-18th-aged-60-sylvia-kristel) is talking about a porn star. I am confused about the last sentence. Does it mean that "That way, she could forget the 'immodesty' and forget of what she was doing" ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without more context, but from this short bit, it looks like she was concerned about the obvious immodesty of performing in a pornographic movie, but by concentrating on the dramatic line readings, she was able to avoid thinking about the actual pornography part.

Comment: So no, it does not mean that she forgot what she was doing. She forgot the immodesty OF what she was doing; she forgot the immodest nature of what she was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Her actions are seen as immoral to her and quite crude. So she dedicated herself to learning the acting portion of her performance so that she could forget how vulgar her actions were. She was essentially trying to make herself feel better about it by taking pride in the acting portion.